# Divide values from one column with corresponding values in another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns `person_type` and `time_in`. I am trying to find the percentage of a `person_type` in each corresponding hour. My database looks like:

```
person_type || time_in
FT             N/A
FT             0
FT             4
FT             22
FT             23
NL             1
NL             2
NL             3
NL             4
NL             4
```

I am trying to create a query to return the following output:

```
% FT        || time_in
100            N/A
100            0
0              1
0              2
0              3
33             4
100            22
100            23
```

I have tried the following code:

```
select (
(select count(*) from delivery where person_type = 'FT')
/count(*)) as 'FT %', time_in
from delivery
group by hour
order by hour;
```

The issue here is my subquery returns 5 for every time_in value so my current output looks like:

```
% FT        || time_in
500            N/A
500            0
500            1
500            2
500            3
166            4
500            22
500            23
```

If I group by time_in in my subquery then I get an error message saying that the query is returning more than one value.

Comment: Don't use a sub query use conditional aggregation see my answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.  For this purpose, I think that `avg()` is the simplest logic:

```
select time_in,
       avg( person_type = 'FT' ) * 100 as percent_ft
from delivery
group by time_in
order by time_in;
```